# Applying the Poincaré Recurrence Theorem to Billiards

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I am studying [this](https://digitalcommons.coastal.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1022&context=honors-theses) application of Poincaré Recurrence Theorem and I have some questions.

1 - it states that If *$S$ is a bounded space with measure $µ$
and $T : S \to S$ is a measure-preserving transformation, then for any set with
positive measure $B \subseteq S$, the subset $A \subseteq B$ of points that never recur to $B$
has measure zero.*

Does $S$ must be bounded? All the other references that I've seen does not require it. Why does the author require $S$ to be bounded?

2 - Page 12:  *The Poincaré recurrence theorem states that the
set of points in $B$ that will never return to $B$ no matter how many time
intervals are observed has measure zero. **This means that with probability
one, the system’s initial configuration is not in this subset, and eventually
will return to $B$.***

I don't get this sentence. How can we guarantee that the poll balls are not in this mesuare zero subset? And then the system's initial configuration will return to $B$?

Again, on page 13, *Finally, although the recurrence theorem guarantees recurrence with probability one, it does not guarantee that the system recurs for every single point
in B. In fact, there may be infinitely many points that do not return to B.
However, the theorem does assert that the set of points in B that do not
return to B has measure zero – even though B has positive measure. **Thus,
although it is possible that the billiard table’s initial configuration is one that
never recurs, it is a zero probability event; consequently, the probability of
recurrence is one.***

I don't get this, is it saying that the it is possible that the billiard table's initial configuration can never recurs or it will always recur?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Answering directly to your questions:

$1$. Of course that $S$ need not be bounded.

$2$. "This means that with probability one, the system’s initial configuration is not in this subset, and eventually will return to $B$."

is intended to mean

"This means that with probability one, the system’s initial configuration is not in this subset, and **so it is with probability one in the complement of that subset, which means that it** eventually will return to $B$."

$3$. "Thus, although it is possible that the billiard table’s initial configuration is one that never recurs, it is a zero probability event; consequently, the probability of recurrence is one."

is intended to mean

"Thus, although it is possible that the billiard table’s initial configuration is one that never recurs, **in which case** it is a zero probability event; consequently, **the billiard table’s initial configuration is one that recurs with probability one and so** the probability of recurrence is one."

*I'm not trying to change the language, only to add the missing text. The language could improve substantially in this thesis.*

Note that the author makes a very basic error in the text that you quote: he seems to think that the opposite of "recurring" is to "never recur". This is a nonsense since points can recur finitely often.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I think I am misunderstanding something. I still do not understand "Thus, although it is possible that the billiard table’s initial configuration is one that never recurs, in which case it is a zero probability event; consequently, the billiard table’s initial configuration is one that recurs with probability one and so the probability of recurrence is one." I still do not get it, for me you are saying things that are conflicting.
And when you say ''This is a nonsense since points can recur finitely often.'' How is that?
thanks again.

Comment: "How is that?" It is a matter of giving examples: points can return (nobody uses "recur" to be honest) any number of times and then stop returning. It is of course hard to give examples. You need to explain what is it that you don't understand, not simply say that you don't understand it. In fact what I wrote is crystal clear. Anyways, why do you want to read such a bad text?

Comment: My question is: if I get my initial state $B$ such that there is a couple balls inside $B$. Now I have a subset $A \subseteq B$ of points that do not return to $B$. It is possible that the poll balls are inside of $B$, right? When you say ''Thus, ..., in which case it is a zero probability event'', I think that the answer is yes, but then when you say  ''consequently, ....''  I think that the answer is no, that is, that the balls are never inside $A$ and will always return to $B$.

Comment: I am looking for a application of the Poincaré Recurrence Theorem, and this text was the only one that I've found that do some math and discussions. Could you give me another reference, please?

Comment: Note that $B$ is a set of positions and velocities, not of balls. So $A$ is a subset of positions and velocities. Some of them will return to $B$ (almost all of them, infinitely many times), but some won't (a set of volume zero, thus with probability $0$). Perhaps you can have a look at https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642280894